# error in inet_ntoa function-

Tags: c, raw-sockets, inet

I am implementing raw sockets in C linux.
Function below is giving error *incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘inet_ntoa’* 
Earlier it was running fine. But now this error is coming. Why so?-

```
//packet is received from socket using recvfrom call.
char* ParseIPHeader(unsigned char *packet,int len)
{
    struct ethhdr *ethernet_header;
    struct iphdr *ip_header;

    ethernet_header=(struct ethhdr *)packet;

    if(ntohs(ethernet_header->h_proto)==ETH_P_IP)
    {
        if(len>=(sizeof(struct ethhdr)+sizeof(struct iphdr)))
        {
            ip_header=(struct iphdr*)(packet+sizeof(struct ethhdr));

            printf("Dest IP address: %s \n",inet_ntoa(ip_header->daddr));  //error here
            printf("Source IP address: %s \n",inet_ntoa(ip_header->saddr)); //error here
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I think that inet_ntoa expects an in_addr parameter and you give it a uint32 parameter (daddr)

Comment: @Jayesh I have included arpa/inet.h as i mentioned before some time, it was working fine as well. And the other options you mentioned in your second comment are also not removing the error. :)

Comment: @Jayesh Also inet_ntoa is known to compiler but it's giving error regarding argument. How to solve it?

Comment: Read manual page please: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?inet_ntoa - `char *inet_ntoa(struct in_addr in);`

Comment: @someuser read.. but still don't know how to correct it.

Comment: `inet_ntoa(*((struct in_addr *)&(ip_header->saddr)))` I think.

Comment: @someuser Thanks. It worked.. :) I dint put & , therefore could not correct it in one go.